# C: addressing to inner structure in linked list

Tags: c, pointers

I have a structure that is going to be a linked list. But at first I cannot read values from inner structes. It sounds complicated, but here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Address
{
    char city[50];
};

struct Task
{
    char fullName[255];
    struct Address address;
};

struct TaskList
{
    struct Task* task;
    struct TaskList* next;
};

struct Task createTask()
{
    struct Task task;
    struct Address address;
    printf("Enter full name: ");
    scanf("%s", task.fullName);
    printf("Enter the city: ");
    scanf("%s", address.city);
    task.address = address;

    return task;
}

void addTask(struct TaskList *head)
{
    struct TaskList* temp;
    struct Task task = createTask();
    temp->task = &task;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}

int main()
{
    struct TaskList *head;
    head = NULL;
    addTask(head);
    printf("%s", head->task->address.city);

    return 0;
}
```

When I launch the app and enter some data, the process crashes with the following code:

> Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 11.102 s

How in fact should I address inner structures and their fields?

Comment: `struct Task task` in your `addTask(struct TaskList*)` function only exists on the stack. If you take the address, you get undefined behavior when accessing the memory after the function has returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple memory issues with this code, here is the explanation and the solution for one of them.

Valgrind shows:

```
==1249== Invalid read of size 8
==1249==    at 0x40051B: main (/tmp/t.c:48)
==1249==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

It looks like that the `head` is still null when you print it in line 48. `addTask` doesn't change the local variable `head` in `main`. Fix it like this:

```
struct TaskList* addTask(struct TaskList *head)
{
    struct TaskList* temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);
    struct Task* task = malloc(sizeof *task);
    *task = createTask();
    temp->task = task;
    temp->next = head;
    return temp;
}
int main()
{
    struct TaskList *head;
    head = NULL;  
    head = addTask(head);
    printf("%s", head->task->address.city);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works as I wanted to. I tried to use `malloc`, but some undefined behavior was at the end. In fact I cannot understand malloc concept, but such construction should work fine. It is more convenient in C++, in my mind.

Comment: Pointer "temp" in addTask() is not initialized and referencing to structure fields through this uninitialized pointer tends to segmentation fault. Moreover struct Task "task" is on the stack and using it outside this function is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

The `task` created by `createTask` is allocated on stack, it will be freed after the function(`createTask`) ends. Use `malloc` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass head pointer by poiner to addTask() to change it inside it:

```
struct TaskList* addTask(struct TaskList **head)
```

And set it in it:

```
*head = temp;
```

And createTask() must explore malloc() and for [scanf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) calls pointers to variables must be used:

```
struct Task *createTask()
{
    struct Task *task = malloc(sizeof(struct Task));
    printf("Enter full name: ");
    scanf("%s", &task->fullName);
    printf("Enter the city: ");
    scanf("%s", &task->address.city);
    return task;
}
```

As Address structure is a part of Task - there is only one call to malloc().

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Address
{
    char city[50];
};

struct Task
{
    char fullName[255];
    Address address;
 };

struct TaskList
{
    Task* task;
    TaskList* next;
 };

 struct Task createTask()
 {
    Task task;
    Address address;
    printf("Enter full name: ");
    scanf("%s", task.fullName);
    printf("Enter the city: ");
    scanf("%s", address.city);
    task.address = address;

   return task;
```

}

Also your "head" pointer is null, intialize it properly

Try using it this way remove keyword "struct" , it must be working fine